# Code not excuting correctly the delay is not working at all any help is appreciated

Tags: c++, c, embedded, atmega, windows-embedded-compact

Delay is not working after burning the code on at mega i tried most of stuff i found online but nothing worked any help is highly appreciated thanks in advance.

````
while (1)
      {
      PORTC.0 == 1 ;
      delay_ms(2000);
      PORTC.0 == 0 ; 
      delay_ms(2000); 

      }
}```
````

Comment: What is the point of `PORTC.0 == 1;` and `PORTC.0 == 0 ;` Those are comparisons that throw the result away. You could replace the loop with `while(1) {delay_ms(4000);}` which seems pointless.

Comment: What is `PORTC.0` ?

Comment: i am making port C0 high and low the same idea as blinking the led but using Codevision

Comment: the code ran on protous perfectly yet when i burned the code on atmega16 it always give me 5V on port C0

Comment: That is expected because `==` is comparison, `=`is assignment.

Comment: `PORTC.0` is not valid C or C++ and will not compile on any compiler. I doubt this is the real code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want just `delay()`

Also, you don't want to use the comparison operator `==`. You want to use the assignment operator `=`. I am assuming that you are trying to blink an LED on and OFF

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/time/delay/